# How can I use Linkify with Django_tables2

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I have read a few similar questions and all the docs I can find on this but I am still not able to understand the solution. I have built my model to have a player, the text description of a keyboard and a url to it. I want to show in a table the player, the keyboard and i want to have the keyboard text have the url column embedded within it. Any help would be appreciated.

Models.py:

```
class player_hardware(models.Model):
Player = models.TextField(blank = False, primary_key = True)
keyboard =  models.TextField(blank = True, max_length = 200)
keyboard_url = models.TextField(blank = True, max_length = 200)
```

Views.py:

```
class PlayerListView(SingleTableView):
model = player_hardware
table_class = PersonTable
template_name = 'application/playerlist.html'
```

Tables.py

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):
class Meta:
    model = player_hardware
    template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
    fields = ("Player", "keyboard")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the keyboard_url is to an external website, it's simpler to add the url link in a custom render_field method on the Table.

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):

    def render_keyboard(self, record):
        return mark_safe(f'<a href="{record.keyboard_url}">{record.keyboard}</a>')
```

The linkify field appears to be more for internal urls, but if you absolutely wanted to use linkify to create an external link, it would look like:

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):

    keyboard = tables.Column(linkify=self.get_keyboard_url)

    def get_keyboard_url(self, record):
        return record.keyboard_url
```

Comment: Wow that was much easier than what I was expecting. Thank you!